# Passing variables from Javascript to PHP using AJAX and Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to write a simple web page to send data from an html page to a php script and receive some data back from the php. I am attempting to do this with ajax, but the php script never even runs.

This is the HTML.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').click(function(){
    alert("hi");
        var clickBtnValue = "hi";
        var ajaxurl = 'add.php',
        data =  {'action': clickBtnValue};
        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
            // Response div goes here.
            alert("action performed successfully");
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

This is the PHP.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
    switch ($_POST['action']) {
        case 'insert':
            insert();
            break;
        case 'select':
            select();
            break;
    }
}

function select() {
    echo "The select function is called.";
    exit;
}

function insert() {
    echo "The insert function is called.";
    exit;
}
?>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.js"></script>
```

This is included as well. I really can't figure out why it doesn't run the PHP script. Am I attempting to use out of date commands?

EDIT : Added the button HTML code

```
 <div class="ui one column stackable center aligned page grid">
    <div class="column twelve wide">
        <form>
            <button id = "submit_query" type = "button" class="ui green button">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don' t see any HTML there with a class of "button".

Comment: Do you get the JS alert? Are there any messages / errors in your browser console?

Comment: Check your network traffic in the browser. It will at least tell you if the route to add.php is correct. If not check that the directory you specified is correct for the file. Also as Jon Stirling has mentioned check your console for any JS related errors

Comment: I receive this error message - "cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https."

Answer (score 0):

the reason php script is not executing is, it fails to satisfy switch statement

because you are passing value "hi" instead of "insert" or "select"

```
var clickBtnValue = "insert";//here value is hi instead of insert or select
        var ajaxurl = 'add.php',
        data =  {'action': clickBtnValue};
        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
            // Response div goes here.
            alert("action performed successfully");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Html form

```
<div class="ui one column stackable center aligned page grid">
        <div class="column twelve wide">
            <form>
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value "insert"> <!-- either insert or select -->
                <button id = "submit_query" type = "button" class="ui green button">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In your Js edit it accordingly

```
    $("form").submit(function(event){

        // stop the form from submitting
        event.preventDefault();

        var $form = $(this);

        // Get input from all the fields
        var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");

        // Serialize the data in the form
        var serializedData = $form.serialize();

        $.post('/add.php', serializedData, function(response) {
        // Log the response to the console
            console.log("Response: "+response);
        });

    });
```

With this you can pass the data to the add.php

Next you can fetch it using

```
        if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
        switch ($_POST['action']) {
            case 'insert':
                insert();
                break;
            case 'select':
                select();
                break;
        }
    }

    function select() {
        echo "The select function is called.";
    }

    function insert() {
        echo "The insert function is called.";
    }
```